# Disable eslint-prettier with vue on annoying vue's html formatting

Tags: html, vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

```
<template>
    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1" onclick="console.log('testing...');" style="display: block;">
        HOW CAN I LEAVE ME CODE LIKE THIS!!!!?
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<template>
    <div
        class="d-flex flex-grow-1"
        onclick="console.log('testing...');"
        style="display: block;"
    >
        eslint-prettier KEEPS CHANGING MY CODE LIKE THIS...    SOOOOOOOOO ANNOYING!!!
    </div>
</template>
```

---

.eslintrc.json

```
{
    "root": true,
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "es6": true,
        "browser": true
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "plugins": [],
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": [
                "**/*.vue"
            ],
            "parser": "vue-eslint-parser",
            "parserOptions": {
                "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser"
            },
            "plugins": [],
            "extends": [
                "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
                "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
                "plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended",
                "prettier/vue",
                "plugin:prettier/recommended"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-alpha.0",
    "prettier": "^2.0.4",
  }
```

setting.json

```
{
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "eslint.validate": [
    "javascript",
    "vue"
  ]
}
```

---

I have **vetur** and **eslint** installed on VS Code. I am working fine with this set of configure. However, this line wrap setting is very annoying. Anyone can give me advice on how can I disable line wrapping for vue's html or even disable formatting for vue's html?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also post the code for `.eslintrc`

Comment: Do you have a .eslintrc file?

Comment: Sorry I missed it.   Have edited the question

Comment: Don't use prettier if you disagree with its settings. Imo the formatting you disagree with is a huge improvement in readability, though. And btw, using either of `onclick` or `style` is widely considered harmful and really bad practice.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Same boat, 4-15 lines instead of 1 is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

```
"rules": {
  "max-len": ["error", 140, 2, {
     ignoreComments: false,
     ignoreRegExpLiterals: true,
     ignoreStrings: false,
     ignoreTemplateLiterals: false,
  }],
   "vue/max-attributes-per-line": "off"
}
```

Add this to your rules, in your `.eslintrc` file you can adjust the number 140 to your preference so that it doesn't wrap the files to 80 characters which is default.

Comment: this does not work... as long as  "plugin:prettier/recommended" is present, those lines wrapped...    seems it is because of default `printWidth` of prettier is `80`... How can I bypass it only for vue template?

Comment: You have freed me from my own personal inferno. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using Prettier as a code formatter:
On the Prettier config: .prettierrc (create it if doesn't exist) put 120 or 180 for the printwidth. The default is 80.

```
{
  "printWidth": 120
}
```

You can override here other options too.
See the documentation
[Prettier Options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html)